# Updating the DOM with arrays JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, dom, foreach, dom-events

I am having a problem when I try to update the DOM with new information coming from an API.

Every time that I click to add new users, the array displays the old, and new information. Ideally, it would update the array first and then display only the new information. I will attach a picture of what is happening. I would like to every time the user click on add new user, the DOM update with only the information of that new user.

HTML part

```html
<table class="table is-fullwidth table is-hoverable table-info">
   <thead>
          <tr">
              <th title="Channel Name" class="has-text-left"> Channel Name </th>
              <th title="View per week" class="has-text-right"> View per week </th>
          </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody id="body-table">
          <tr id="tr-table">

          </tr> 
    </tbody>
</table>
```

script.js

```javascript
const trline = document.getElementById('body-table')


let usersList = [];

async function getnewUsers(){
    const res = await fetch('https://randomuser.me/api')
    const data = await res.json()
    // create an instance of the results
    const user = data.results[0]
    // create the new user
    const newUser = {
        name:`${user.name.first} ${user.name.last}`,
        social: Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000 )
    }
    // update the new user to the database...
    addData(newUser)  
}

function addData(obj) {
    usersList.push(obj)
    // update the information on the screen
    updateDOM()
}

function updateDOM( providedData = usersList){
    providedData.forEach(item => {
        const element = document.createElement('tr')
        element.innerHTML = `
        <td class="has-text-left cname"> ${item.name} </td>
        <td class="has-text-right cview"> ${item.social} k</td>
        `
        trline.appendChild(element)
    })
}

addUser.addEventListener('click', getnewUsers)
```

Result picture:

[image: loop same information]

Comment: Why do you "pass" the users as default value instead of `updateDOM(usersList)`? o.O

Comment: Either remove the existing table rows before you append the elements from `providedData` or you add a method that only adds one user at a time (the one from `addData()`).

Comment: How I would do if I decided to add a method to add one at a time?

Comment: Like with `updateDOM()`, just without the loop.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem and the solution.
I didn't reset the HTML part to clear before adding a new item. I had to fix the function updateDOM with this: `trline.innerHTML = ''`

After that, the function works fine.

```
function updateDOM( providedData = usersList){
trline.innerHTML = '' // clear everything before adding new stuff

providedData.forEach(item => {
    const element = document.createElement('tr')
    element.innerHTML = `
    <td class="has-text-left cname"> ${item.name} </td>
    <td class="has-text-right cview"> ${item.social} k</td>
    `
    trline.appendChild(element) 
})
```

}

Comment: i don't recommend using `innerHTML` to update the DOM. you will learn a lot from using methods like `element.appendChild`